# Azure Free Trial account VM size is greyed

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have a free trial for azure . I am trying to create an initial windows machine with B1S size ( Free service ) . All the sizes are greyed out . I am in region US ( EAST ) . What can be the problem . I signed out and signed back in, still see the issue

Comment: if you Google using the text _All the sizes are greyed out_ with a filter of past month. You get the below Reddit and other links https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/apuuq2/create_vm_greyed_out_why/
Multiple suggestions one of them being the service limits. Please check with the Azure support or any such links

Comment: Also, please be careful. Check cost management to avoid surprise billings also checkout blogs to secure  your root account.

Comment: @unnik still no luck. I even created a different account and added my credit card.Still see the same issue . There is 200 $ credit available . I am going through the following option Home>Free Services > Create a Virtual machine . So what can be the problem .

Comment: Do you check if you meet the CPU quote?

Answer (score 3):

During the Corona Virus period, Microsoft disable all the vm creation for free trial accounts.