# unable to set size of VM in Azure under free trial account

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am getting familiar with Azure and started using it with a free trial account. I want to create a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter VM in (US) Central US and (Canada) Canada Central region. When trying to select size, which is a require field, all the options show grayed out. 
Is this an expected behaviour? I thought there were no restrictions in how uses the credit for a free trail account.

[select a VM size section in Azure grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXUwO.png)
Can anyone provide guidance?
Thanks

Comment: This is the azure full guide for free account.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/.
hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083091/when-creating-vm-in-azure-select-size-is-greyed-out/61093822#61093822 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783833/azure-free-trial-account-vm-size-is-greyed